# VB.Net Form DirectCast on Forms.Panel

Tags: vb.net

I need to loop through the textboxes of my form, which are located inside a panel. I'm trying to do it like this....

```
For Each Cntrl As Control In DirectCast(Me.Controls(PanelName), Panel).Controls

next
```

The reason I need to feed the panel's name to the loop is because I have two panels that exist in 2 different TabPages. A button exists on each TabPage that performs the same function, but the panels and textboxes have different names. I have the loop inside a function that handles both TabPage button clicks, therefore I need the loop to point to the right panel.

The "PanelName" matches the target panel's name, and the panel is of System.Windows.Form.Panel.

I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." message.

Is this not possible?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but are you sure that at the time you are doing this both (A) the panel hasn't been removed or renamed, and (B) InitializeComponent() has already been called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to cast:

```
For Each Cntrl As Control In PanelName.Controls

Next
```

If all you have is the name of the panel and not the control reference, then you at least need to know which TabPage has the panel:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In TabControl1.TabPages(1).Controls("panel1").Controls

Next
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
Me.Controls.Find(PanelName, True)
```

to return the panel by name while searching child controls recursively.

Comment: Thanks LarsTech. This is what I need, but I did a horrible job describing the situation. I've edited my question, so hopefully it explains it better.

Comment: @JoeB Are these panels created dynamically?  In your posted code, Me.Controls won't work since the panels are in your TabPage.Controls collection.